# How to process data from pipe with another command , linux command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I have a directory with many links.

First i need to enumerate and list the links that matches the string 'standford'.

Then find inside those links the lines that contains the string 'standford' and enumerate them.

I have this:

```
ls -b |nl -s '. ' -w 1 |grep 'stanford'
```

which is giving me the links that matches ´standford´and its number like this.

```
261. http_^^www-pcd.stanford.edu^hci^courses^cs193e.html
262. http_^^www-pcd.stanford.edu^hci^courses^cs246.html
263. http_^^www-pcd.stanford.edu^hci^courses^cs247b.html
264. http_^^www-pcd.stanford.edu^hci^courses^cs329.html
265. http_^^www-pcd.stanford.edu^hci^courses^cs377.html
266. http_^^www-pcd.stanford.edu^hci^courses^cs378.html
267. http_^^www-pcd.stanford.edu^hci^courses^cs447.html
```

(the `/` were replaced by `^`, don´t know why, but still can access to the site)

so now i need to access to each of this links to find the string ´standford'.

How do i input this links to be read with another command (cat or grep)?

```
$ ls -b |nl -s '. ' -w 1 |grep 'stanford' |cat ....
```

Comment: Just piping it like that should work. What problem are you having?

Comment: Cat is use to view files, not command outputs, you can, however chain as many greps or similar commands as you wish so `ls -b  | nl -s '. ' -w 1 |grep 'stanford' | grep 246` is valid.

Comment: Nothing is replacing the `/` with `^`, those must be part of the filenames. A filename can't contain `/`, since that's the directory separator.

Comment: but how do i access to the link to find the string ?

Comment: You mean you want to read the *contents* of the files?

Comment: i only want to find the strings inside the links and show them

Comment: Get rid of the line numbering, and use `xargs` to turn the output of one command into the command-line arguments of another command.

Comment: You keep saying links, but it seems like you really mean files.

Comment: yes the link is a file that contains bunch of lines of strings

Comment: `grep somestring *stanford*`

Comment: That will search for `somestring` in all the files whose names contain `stanford`.

Comment: like this?   ls -b |nl -s '. ' -w 1 |grep 'stanford' | grep stanford *stanford*

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.